# Howto use glm constants in c++/opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am programming with just OpenGL and use GLM ([OpenGL Mathematics](https://glm.g-truc.net)). I found out that there is this extension in GLM called "GLM_GTC_constants" that should provide a list of built-in constants. This is how a function header looks in `constants.hpp`:

```
/// Return the pi constant.
/// @see gtc_constants
template <typename genType>
GLM_FUNC_DECL GLM_CONSTEXPR genType pi();
```

The function itself looks like this (`constants.inl`):

```
template <typename genType>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER GLM_CONSTEXPR genType pi()
{
    return genType(3.14159265358979323846264338327950288);
}
```

Now I'm wondering how to use this function.

---

```
glm::pi();
```

Using the function like above doesn't work.

```
float PI = glm::pi();
```

The code above, for example, gives me this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘pi()’
```

I searched the documentation but did not find a usage example of those constants anywhere.

Comment: No Intellisense ? ;)

Comment: I use CLion, it autocompletes the pi() function as written above.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Type should be specified explicitly for using this templated function, since there's no argument deduction.

`glm::pi<float>()` should do the trick